# Having trouble querying by dates using the Java Cassandra Spark SQL Connector

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to use Spark SQL to query a table by a date range. For example, I'm trying to run an SQL statement like: SELECT * FROM trip WHERE utc_startdate >= '2015-01-01' AND utc_startdate <= '2015-12-31' AND deployment_id = 1 AND device_id = 1. When I run the query no error is being thrown but I'm not receiving any results back when I would expect some. When running the query without the date range I am getting results back.

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("SparkTest")
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.native.port", "9042")
    .set("spark.cassandra.connection.rpc.port", "9160");
JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
JavaCassandraSQLContext sqlContext = new JavaCassandraSQLContext(context);
sqlContext.sqlContext().setKeyspace("mykeyspace");

String sql = "SELECT * FROM trip WHERE utc_startdate >= '2015-01-01' AND utc_startdate < '2015-12-31' AND deployment_id = 1 AND device_id = 1";
JavaSchemaRDD rdd = sqlContext.sql(sql);
List<Row> rows = rdd.collect(); // rows.size() is zero when I would expect it to contain numerous rows.
```

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE trip (
    device_id bigint,
    deployment_id bigint,
    utc_startdate timestamp,
    other columns....
    PRIMARY KEY ((device_id, deployment_id), utc_startdate)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (utc_startdate ASC);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What does your table schema (in particular, your PRIMARY KEY definition) look like?  Even without seeing it, I am fairly certain that you are seeing this behavior because you are not qualifying your query with a partition key.  Using the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive will filter the rows by `date` (assuming that is your clustering key), but that is not a good solution for a big cluster or large dataset.

Let's say that you are querying users in a certain geographic region.  If you used region as a partition key, you could run this query, and it would work:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE region='California'
AND date >= '2015-01-01' AND date <= '2015-12-31';
```

Give Patrick McFadin's article on [Getting Started with Timeseries Data](http://planetcassandra.org/blog/getting-started-with-time-series-data-modeling/) a read.  That has some good examples that should help you.

Comment: Thanks Bryce. I've updated my question to include the table schema. I'm still not receiving results back from spark when including the partition key and the date range. If I remove the date range from the query, and just query by device_id and deployment_id, I am receiving results back from Spark. I'm wondering if perhaps I'm not writing the query properly for Spark SQL. I've tried searching for some documentation on this, but had no luck. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @BrianDiCasa That is strange.  After reading your comment, I do wonder if that is a SparkSQL issue.  I will say though, that your partition keys (`device_id` and `deployment_id`) together may be too high cardinality to allow querying by a date range to really be useful.

Comment: @BrianDiCasa Also found a similar question here, which might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028926/spark-cassandra-connector-range-query-on-partition-key

Comment: I'm curious what you mean by the partition key being too high of a cardinality? Does this imply that the data would be split across too many nodes (by device_id and deployment_id) that it would make querying by utc_startdate inefficient? Would the situation improve if deployment_id was declared an int rather than bigint? Pretty new to Cassandra, so I do appreciate the help!

Comment: Admittedly, I did make that statement without knowing too much about your data model.  But what I meant, was that if `device_id` and `deployment_id` only store one row (as-in, they are unique to each CQL row) then you'll only ever return one row for each combination, which will make `ORDER BY` or date range querying utterly useless.  But if each `device_id`/`deployment_id` combination will return several rows, then it makes sense.  Basically, if your partition keys are too unique (high cardinality) it negates the benefits of the "wide row" concept, and you won't have any data to sort.